# unterminated function-like macro invocation

Tags: cocos2d-x

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
 {
    bool bRet = false;
    do {
        CC_BREAK_IF(!CCLayerColor::initWithColor( ccc4(255,255,255,255));
    } while (0);
 }s
```

my cocos2d-x is the last versions, error at CC_BREAK_IF(!CCLayerColor::initWithColor( ccc4(255,255,255,255)); what can i do ? my ide is xcode6.2

in the older versions, code as above, i have a question: initWithColor is not static function why it can be called by CCLayerColor?

Comment: ps: you return before break-if

Comment: oh, sorry, i found it . i have edit it.

Answer (score 0):

In HelloWorldScene.h

Change

```
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::CCLayer
```

To

```
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::CCLayerColor
```

Change this line from

```
CCSprite *bg1 = CCSprite::create("abc");
```

To

```
CCSprite *bg1 = CCSprite::create("abc.png");
```

Use do while loop(you have written "s" instead of while in the end)

Comment: oh,no, sorry, my question has some error. now ,i have corrected it,thanks.